# Getting the path to a .class file of a dynamically loaded Class in JAVA

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, dynamic-class-loaders, reflections

I'm looking to instantiate and map all classes in my class path of a given type.

I've done the scan using the `Reflections` library, and got a list of classes that were loaded.

Then, when I'm mapping them, I'm checking for conflicts (the key is the simple class name).

When that happens I would like to throw an exception, pointing out the fully qualified name of the conflicting classes, as well as the path they were loaded from (for instance in which `JARs` one might find each).

I realize one may load a class from memory as well, but assuming I was loading it from a `JAR` on disk, I wonder if there's any way of getting that path...

See code snippet below:

```
if (isConflictingFactoryRegistered(key, myFactory)) {
        Class<? extends MyFactory> class1 = factoryMap.get(key).getClass();
        Class<? extends MyFactory> class2 = myFactory.getClass();
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("Found two conflicting factories for " + key
                    + ": 1. " + class1 + " in " + getClass().getResource(class1.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI() +
                       " 2. " + class2 + " in " + getClass().getResource(class2.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } else {
        factoryMap.put(myFactory.getName(), myFactory);
    }
```

This code does compile - but it won't work; getClass().getResource(class1.getSimpleName()+".class") returns null.  How can I get the path to the `.class` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you replace

```
throw new RuntimeException("Found two conflicting factories for " + key
  + ": 1. " + class1 + " in " + getClass().getResource(class1.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI() +
  " 2. " + class2 + " in " + getClass().getResource(class2.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI());
```

with

```
throw new RuntimeException("Found two conflicting factories for " + key
  + ": 1. " + class1 + " in " + class1.getResource(class1.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI() + 
 " 2. " + class2 + " in " + class2.getResource(class2.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI());
```

This works for two arbitrary classes on my machine.

In general, I think that `Class.getResource()` can only find resources available to the same ClassLoader that loaded that specific class - as per [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29),

> This method delegates to this object's class loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the method delegates to ClassLoader.getSystemResource(java.lang.String).

I suspect that if you look at `getClass().getClassLoader()` and `class1.getClassLoader()` in your example, you may find that they are different.

Comment: A duh moment.. That did it. Thank you